# RabbitMQ C# Client recovering from node failure on cluster with quorum queues

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, client, cluster-computing

I've set-up a three node RabbitMQ cluster with a **quorum durable queue**.

I'm trying to find out how to implement a robust way to keep things running both on the producer and the consumer side (two .NET Core processes) in case of node failure.

I'm using the following options on the `ConnectionFactory` class:

```cs
var factory = new ConnectionFactory
{
    HostName = hostname,
    AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
    TopologyRecoveryEnabled = true,
    VirtualHost = vhost
};
```

however, after starting the producer & consumer test processes (which attempt to flood the queue), whenever I stop the master node on the cluster, the clients never recover from this situation, and an `OperationInterruptedException` is thrown on each call to `BasicPublish` (on the producer) or `BasicAck` (on the consumer).

The clients connect to the cluster using a random ip choosen from the three nodes (as given from round-robin dns resolution).

I've read somewhere that for *durable classic non-mirrored queues* this is the expected behavior, but what about quorum queues? Shouldn't they be a more efficient version of mirrored queues (although with some limitations)?

Is there a way to recover from a single node failure without implementing all the reconnection logic in my clients?

Answer (score 1):

> The clients connect to the cluster using a random ip choosen from the
> three nodes (as given from round-robin dns resolution).

The problem is likely to be caused by DNS cache. E.g. producer/consumer DNS-resolved the hostname to a single ip address and then cached it (there is a DNS cache in .NET), causing the RabbitMQ client to always connect to the same RabbitMQ node (which could be shut down).
There are at least 3 approaches for making the failover process more robust:

- pass multiple hostnames or ip addresses of the RabbitMQ cluster nodes to the RabbitMQ client
- put RabbitMQ nodes behind a level-4 load balancer and configure the RabbitMQ client to connect to the load balancer instead of connecting directly to the cluster nodes
- disable DNS cache

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in `ConnectionFactory` class, you can specify list of HostNames while creating a connection (not on the step of declaring factory). Have you tries this one?

```
// Summary:
//     Create a connection using a list of hostnames using the configured port. By default
//     each hostname is tried in a random order until a successful connection is found
//     or the list is exhausted using the DefaultEndpointResolver. The selection behaviour
//     can be overriden by configuring the EndpointResolverFactory.
//
// Parameters:
//   hostnames:
//     List of hostnames to use for the initial connection and recovery.
//
// Returns:
//     Open connection
//
// Exceptions:
//   T:RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException:
//     When no hostname was reachable.
public IConnection CreateConnection(IList<string> hostnames);
```